# How come I get "This is a 'espresso10wifi'" when I try to flash recovery?

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1, clockworkmod-recovery

I'm trying to adb-sideload a new recovery (Philz Touch Recovery n5110) I get,

```
This package is for a 'konowifi.5110.GT-N5110.konawifixx' devices: this is a 'espresso10wifi'.
E: Error in /tmp/update.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Samsung N5110 is the Galaxy Note 8.  The "espresso10wifi" is a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (your device).

It's not flashing because you're flashing the wrong file for your device.